# OpenXML freeze-fixed ID for w:tags

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have a j**ava program** that **search rsidR="00CA303F"** inside document.xml(unzipped of DOCX).

```
<w:sdtContent>
<w:r w:rsidR="00CA303F">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="18"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="18"/>
        <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>17-Jan-14</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:sdtContent>
```

**The problem**: if i change something like the date in the docx and after i save the file, this **rsidR change!** and im not able to find it next time in my program.

**How i can freeze-fixed it? or which other fixed-element can i add to w:r for find it after saving file?**

*Solutions(not working) that i tryed: I added other tags(hoping they will not change), i tryed for example: w:rsidRDefault, w:id, w:val, w:rsidRPr to this w:r, but Word wont be able to open file docx after.*

Answer (score 0):

Word or the OpenXML file format do not offer a direct way to add an ID to an element, which is also persisted if the document is edited.

As a workaround, you can create a character style which you then apply to the run of text you are interested in. Then you can search for the `w:rStyle` element with the correct character style in the `w:val` attribute:

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00E05157">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rStyle w:val="MyCharacterStyle"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>17-Jan-14</w:t>
</w:r>
```

Comment: First thx for the answer, I tryed your solution but after save the file docx all your code was overwritten with the same code that i wrote in my first post(i dont know why), if you want other part of the xml i can give to you without problem.

Comment: @Diego87: If you apply the character style to the text part in your document and save the file, the character style would also be written to the output document like in my sample Open XML.

Comment: <w:sdtContent>    
<w:r w:rsidR="00CA303F">
<w:rPr>
<w:rStyle w:val="hps"/>
<w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
<w:b/>
<w:sz w:val="18"/>
<w:szCs w:val="18"/>
<w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>17-Jan-14</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:sdtContent>
where is the error? is the same of your sample?
if i save docx, this code will be overwritten without w:rStyle
(im pretty new with ooxml, sry)

Comment: @Diego87: You also need to make sure that the character style is a valid, existing character style. If the character style does not exist yet in the document, you will have to add it.

Comment: exist for sure because i copied it from other w:rStyle on the same document

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to assign a unique id to the *containing* `w:sdt` (in the descendant `w:sdtPr/w:id/@w:val`). See for example the docx4java documentation for [sdtPr](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/sdtPr.html).

A good explanation of rsid's, and how they are used by MS Word, is in [What's up with all those rsid's](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_jones/2006/12/11/whats-up-with-all-those-rsids/). In many application it is harmless to completely ignore them.